# SQL Server trigger compare inserted event date to existings records date

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I have a SQL Server trigger I am working on and can't seem to get the inserted date to compare against a date column I have setup in another table. Here is the trigger I am working on:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGNAME 
ON TABLE 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @REC INT   

    SELECT @REC = COUNT(*) 
    FROM INSERTED I    
    WHERE I.ID IS NOT NULL        
      AND I.COL2 = 'TEST'

    IF (@REC > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @REC = COUNT(*) 
        FROM INSERTED I                 
        WHERE I.DATE > (SELECT DISTINCT S.DATE FROM TABLE1 S 
                        WHERE I.PARENT_ID = S.PARENT_ID)

        IF (@REC > 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE STATEMENT HERE
        END
    END
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here but the date column from Table1 is the same for the group of records with the same parent id.

Comment: No, it is not enough information.  What do you want to do?  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Comment: Not at all clear what you're trying to do. Bear in mind that SQL Server triggers fire once *per statement*, not once *per row*. That means that whatever logic you want to apply here may encounter a situation where *some* of the inserted rows match your criteria and some of them do not, at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a DATETIME variable to store the Table1.Date value.
Then do the compare.  And it might be just me but I like to use the inserted table by all lowercase letters.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGNAME 
ON TABLE 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @REC INT   
    DECLARE @MyDate DateTime

    SET @MyDate = (SELECT DISTINCT S.DATE FROM TABLE1 S 
                    INNER JOIN inserted ON inserted.PARENT_ID = S.PARENT_ID)

    SELECT @REC = COUNT(*) 
    FROM INSERTED I    
    WHERE I.ID IS NOT NULL        
      AND I.COL2 = 'TEST'

    IF (@REC > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @REC = COUNT(*) 
        FROM INSERTED I                 
        WHERE I.DATE > @MyDate

    IF (@REC > 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE STATEMENT HERE
    END
END
```

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Your trigger is an error ("subquery returned more than one result...") just waiting to happen.

Comment: yeah, I understand inserted can contain multiple rows, but the application I am working with only inserts one row at a time so I'm not too worried about this for now. Thanks for the advice though.